# How to connect Azure Devops with GitHub without giving it access to all repositories?

Tags: azure-devops

When I try to authorize Azure Devops to get access to my GitHub repositories it wants full access to everything, including:

This application will be able to read and write all public and private repository data. This includes the following:

```
Code
Issues
Pull requests
Wikis
Settings
Webhooks and services
Deploy keys
Collaboration invites
```

But that is to broad access to my taste, how can I just give it access to **specific** **repositories** without giving it access to everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a specific user that has the exact permissions you would grant, create an Access Token for that user to strip some of the requested permissions, don't use the OAuth flow.

[image]